# Program crashes with 0xC000000D and no exceptions - how do I debug it?

Tags: c++, winapi, debugging, visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ 9 Win32 application that uses a third-party library. When a function from that library is called with a certain set of parameters the program crashes with "exception code 0xC000000D".

I tried to attach Visual Studio debugger - no exceptions are thrown (neither C++ nor structured like access violations) and `terminate()` is not called either. Still the program just ends silently.

How does it happen that the program just ends abnormally but without stopping in the debugger? How can I localize the problem?

Comment: is it multithreaded or single-threaded?

Comment: @Simone: One worker thread, several service threads spawned by RPC. We tested synchronization thoroughly, multithreading is unlikely the problem.

Comment: Are you running a release version or a debug version? I've seen weird cases of release versions not stopping in the debugger.

Comment: @Ori Osherov: Both versions behave the same way in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried different OS's? Which one are you running now? Are you linking to the correct dll's? (they should be different for release/debug). (I do think you have done these steps, but just to be sure)

Comment: Have you verified that the 3rd party lib does not call exit(0xd) or some such stunt?

Comment: Just a thought, is it possible that your library is trashing some part of memory leading to a crash and abnormal program termination.  If you had access to a tool such as BoundsChecker, or a similar execution profiler, it might well catch the problem.  You might also check if you have DEP turned on in the linker, and see if the problem persists with DEP turned off, similarly runtime checks in the compilation options.

Comment: A lot of good thoughts - all of these will be caught by WinDbg and you'll know exactly what happened. Another way to catch all of these errors is by using AppVerifier - no need to pay for BoundsChecker.

Comment: Hadn't heard of AppVerifier and my BoundsChecker license is way out of date and expensive even to upgrade.  One to look at, thanks for that Paul!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER, use WinDbg to track down who threw it (i.e. attach WinDbg, `sxe eh` then `g`.

Comment: The OP already said that "attach VS debugger - no exceptions are thrown" ... how would WinDbg change the picture?

Comment: Searching around seems to indicate that there are functions that throw this - but also that there are functions that use STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER as a return value. So maybe nothing is thrown after all ...

Comment: @Martin VS will hide certain kinds of exceptions it doesn't know how to deal with (rarely). Using WinDbg 100% rules out any type of exception.

Comment: I'll try this if we don't get help from the library vendor. I also found this promising KB article on how to use WinDbg in such cases: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313109/en-gb

Comment: @AnaBetts I don't think it does, do you have a source for your claim?

Comment: @Zimano I worked at Microsoft on the user-mode exception handler

Answer (score 2):

Other answers and comments to the question helped a lot. Here's what I did.

I notices that if I run the program under Visual Studio debugger it just ends silently, but if I run it without debugger it crashes with a message box (usual Windows message box saying that I lost my unsaved data and everyone is sooo sorry).

So I started the program wihtout debugger, let it crash and then - while the message box was still there - attached the debugger and hit "Break". Here's the call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()  
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0xc bytes   
kernel32.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()  - 0x48 bytes   
kernel32.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjects@16()  + 0x18 bytes 
faultrep.dll!StartDWException()  + 0x5df bytes  
faultrep.dll!ReportFault()  + 0x533 bytes   
kernel32.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()  + 0x55c bytes
//SomeThirdPartyLibraryFunctionAddress
//SomeThirdPartyLibraryFunctionAddress
//SomeThirdPartyLibraryFunctionAddress
//SomeThirdPartyLibraryFunctionAddress
//OurCodeInvokingThirdPartyLibraryCode
```

so obviously that's some problem inside the trird-party library. According to MSDN, [`UnhandledExceptionFilter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681401%28VS.85%29.aspx) is called in fatal situations and clearly the call is done because of some problem in the library code. So we'll try to work the problem out with the library vendor first.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have source and debugging information for your 3rd party library, you will not be able to step into it with the debugger.  As I see it, your choices are;

- Put together a simple test case illustrating the crash and send it onto the library developer
- Wrap that library function in your own code that checks for illegal parameters and throw an exception / return an error code when they are passed by your own application
- Rewrite the parts of the library that do not work or use an alternative

Very difficult to fix code that is provided as object only

**Edit**  You might also be able to exit more gracefully using __try __finally around your main message loop, something like

```
int CMyApp::Run() 
{
    __try
    {
        int i = CWinApp::Run();
        m_Exitok = MAGIC_EXIT_NO;
        return i;
    }
    __finally
    {
        if (m_Exitok != MAGIC_EXIT_NO)
            FaultHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul, sure, but only in assembler without the PDB.  With the PDB but no source, you get nicely annotate assmebler with labels from the source.  IMO, these are rarely worth hand debugging, as a fix must be done in assembler which is going to be time consuming and cause a future maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I don't think that OP's problem was stepping into the code but rather capturing the exception, which he says doesn't happen.

Comment: But he doesn't want to hand-debug the assembly, he wants a call stack (even a wrong one) of the failure point. If the failure is actually being thrown by the OS, he *will* have symbols for that